# Unity 5: Dropdown UI & gameobjects

Tags: c#, user-interface, logic, unity-game-engine

I Have a drop down, and this dropdown gives me the list of gameobjects that I can Move via slider. Basically what I'm trying to do is to have x , y , z sliders that moves gameobject on each axis. My issues now is with PlayerPrefs. Everything I want works like a charm but the issue is that when I move the gameobject and quit the app, it's not saving. The dropdown is used to choose which gameobject will move. Can anyone assist me?

This is the script that is attached to the Slider.

```
 public enum Axis{
x,y,z
};

public enum Options{
position,scale,fov,particlesystem, ui
};

public Axis axis;
public Options options;
public TMP_InputField inputField;
public TMP_InputField maxSliderInputField;

public Slider slider;
public GameObject gameObject;
public Text text;

Vector3 pos;
Vector3 tempPos;


public string playerPrefsFloatId;
public string playerPrefsStringId;
public string maxValueId;

public GameObject[] iconstoMove; // my Objects that i can choose from dropdown
public TMP_Dropdown dropDown;

if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(playerPrefsFloatId))
    {
        slider.value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(playerPrefsFloatId);
        text.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString(playerPrefsStringId);
        SliderOptions();

        GetAxis();

        Debug.Log ("Have Key" + playerPrefsFloatId);

    }

        void SaveUISettings()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(playerPrefsFloatId, slider.value);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(maxValueId, slider.maxValue);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString(playerPrefsStringId, text.text);

    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}

// i use this to move object depending on axis.
void UiMovement()
{
    switch (axis)
    {
        case Axis.x:
            pos = OnValueDropDownChanged().transform.position;//gameObject.transform.position;
            pos.x = slider.value;
            OnValueDropDownChanged().transform.position = pos;
        Debug.Log ("HI");
        //  gameObject = OnValueDropDownChanged();
        //  gameObject.transform.position = pos;
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
            break;

        case Axis.y:
        pos = OnValueDropDownChanged().transform.position;      
        pos.y = slider.value;
            //gameObject = OnValueDropDownChanged();
        OnValueDropDownChanged().transform.position = pos;
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
            break;

        case Axis.z:
        pos = OnValueDropDownChanged().transform.position;      
            pos.z = slider.value;
            //gameObject = OnValueDropDownChanged();
        OnValueDropDownChanged().transform.position = pos;
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
                break;

        default:
            Debug.LogWarning("Please Choose Axis!");
            break;
    }
}

// This is how i choose my gameobject from the dropdown
private GameObject OnValueDropDownChanged()
{
    if (dropDown.value == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Im Index Number " + "I'm 0");

        // TODO: Movement for 0 Index
    //  Debug.Log (iconstoMove[0].name  + " This is the name " + iconstoMove[0].transform.position + "Transform of the object");
        return iconstoMove[0];
    }


    else if (dropDown.value == 1)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Im Index Number " + "I'm 1");
        return  iconstoMove[1];
    }
    else if (dropDown.value == 2)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Im Index Number " + "I'm 2");
        return  iconstoMove[2];
    }

    else if (dropDown.value == 3)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Im Index Number " + "I'm 3");
        return  iconstoMove[3];
    }

    else if (dropDown.value == 4)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Im Index Number " + "I'm 4");
        return  iconstoMove[4];
    }

    else if (dropDown.value == 5)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Im Index Number " + "I'm 5");
        return  iconstoMove[5];
    }

    else if (dropDown.value == 6)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Im Index Number " + "I'm 6");
        return  iconstoMove[6];
    }

    else if (dropDown.value == 7)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Im Index Number " + "I'm 7");
        return  iconstoMove[7];
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now I have many other slider for other gameobjects that doesn't use dropdown. they all work as I want. The only issue I have is when I choose objects from the dropdown it never saves, What is happening exactly?

Comment: it doesn't appear as though you are calling void `SaveUISettings()` anywhere in your code. is this occurring somewhere else? post this code.

Comment: I am calling , in a differnt function that also calls this function that i posted.

Comment: it doesn't work, even if i call saveUiSetting. i think it's because of the dropdown. What is happeing is that the dropdown has 8 gameojects. and when i move / save i save only the referenced gameobject. I'm not understanding how to do the correct logic behind this